# Why is $P(X>C) = E[1\{X>C\}]$

Tags: statistics

This was found in a line from the proof of the law of large numbers. the $1\{X>C\}$ is the usual indicator function.

Comment: The probability of any event is always the expectation of its indicator function. This is one of the fundamental principles linking probability to expectation.

Comment: Can you please explain this in a manner which would be intuitive to someone not from a stats background?

Comment: @user202723: That doesn't make sense since $1_{\{X>C\}}$ is defined on $\Omega$ and not on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

Define $Y = I\{X>c\}$ then 
$$
EI\{X>c\} =EY = 1P(X>c)+0P(X\le c) = P(X>c).
$$
You can see that $Y \sim Bernoulli ( P(X>c))$.